# Problems with Recursion - unexpected output

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

```
public class recursion {
    void printMessage() {
        System.out.println("Yo!");
    }
    // x = 1, y = 1
    void add (int x, int y) {
    if (x<4) {
            int sum = x + y;
            System.out.println(sum);
            add(sum,x);
            printMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
2
3
5
Yo!
Yo!
Yo!
```

I don't understand why the message is printed three times? Once x exceeds 3, shouldn't the print message function be called just once ??

Comment: Get a paper and write down what the code should do. Then use a debug-function and look what your code is doing.

Comment: @tosob on paper it looks like this. x = 1 y =1. if x is less than 4 then >> sum = 1 + 1. Print 2. Call function (2,1). if 2 < 4 then >> sum = 2 +1. Print 3. Call function (3,2). If 3 < 4 then >> sum = 3 + 2. Call function (5,3). 5 is not < 4 so print message. I don't understand why the print message is called as a stack 3 times. From what people are saying, its because the add function has been called three times ? This is starting to make a bit more sense now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printMessage()` is called for each time the recursive method `add()` calls itself.

Since `add()` calls itself 3 times, `printMessage()` is also called 3 times, and prints its message 3 times.

If you want it printed just once, call it only when `x>=4`:

```
void add (int x, int y) {
    if (x<4) {
        int sum = x + y;
        System.out.println(sum);
        add(sum,x);
    } else {
      printMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Eran When I wrote the post, I was expecting the output to be 2, Yo!, 3, Yo! and 5, Yo!.  I think I'm starting to get it now. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Newbie in that case, why did you write in your question "shouldn't the print message function be called just once"?

Answer (score 1):

each time you call this function it will print "Yo!". If you would like to print it only once, you should edit it like this:

```
void add (int x, int y) {
    if (x<4) {
        int sum = x + y;
        System.out.println(sum);
        add(sum,x);
        return;
    }
    printMessage();
}
```

"return" will break the function and it won't continue your code in it (printMessage()).

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It will be called every time the add() function call returns. Basically it tells you how many times your add function executed.